# How to keep the current option in group button flutter

Tags: flutter

I was used group_button package from flutter to make user can select many options. After upgrading the library to version 5.0.0 or above, the selectedButtons property has been deprecated. I was save options of user by it but no I can't use it now. I was use it as:

```
  GroupButton(
                      selectedButtons: setSelectedBtn(index),
                      isRadio: false,
                      spacing: 10,
                      onSelected: (i, isSelected) =>
                          onFilterSelect(index, i, isSelected),
                      buttons: widget.filters[index].value
                          .map((e) => e.value)
                          .toList())),




  setSelectedBtn(index) {
    List<int> result = [];
    var valueSet = widget.filters[index].value;
    bool isSelected = valueSet
        .firstWhere((element) => element.isSelected,
            orElse: () => CategoryFilterValues("", false))
        .isSelected;
    if (!isSelected) {
      return result;
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < valueSet.length; index++) {
      if (valueSet.elementAt(index).isSelected) {
        result.add(index);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

[group_button](https://pub.dev/packages/group_button)

How I can save the options now in new version? Anyone can help me to do it.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GroupButtonController.
Controller have list of methods to interact with options.

**selectIndex(int i)** - Select button by index in radio type 
**unselectIndex(int i)** - Unselect button by index in checkbox and radio type 
... etc.

More docs and examples you can find [here](https://github.com/Frezyx/group_button/blob/master/lib/src/utils/controller/controller.dart)